# how to reduce kernel boot time?

Tags: linux, boot, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

How can i reduce kernel boot time? i don't know why it is taking this large value of time although when i have installed my os was 4sec ?

Output of `systemd-analyze` is:

```
Startup finished in 1.564s (firmware) + 3.402s (loader) + 10.775s 
(kernel) + 1.633s (userspace) = 17.376s
```

and the output of `dmesg` is: [boot](http://pastebin.com/kmLaLuzC).

Note is use ssd so it's high value and should take at most 4 sec.

## Update

*I don't know if other installed kernel affect boot time anyway here's a screen shot of kernels:*

[image]

Comment: Just an idea: look for _"big time jumps"_ in your dmesg: around 3 seconds for BIOS (check for it) `pci 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001`, 4 seconds between 6 and 10. PS> there are  12 seconds for `wlp2s0` it seems to me a _bit_ slow :-) Good Luck

Comment: Test your boots multiple times. Are they consistently slow?

Comment: is other kernel installed affect boot time and what happen if i remove the one i don't use http://i.imgur.com/UQZ3WjD.png @Hastur & Mark Stosberg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one culprit relates to EHCI Handoff.  - see the lines

```
[    0.394166] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.394182] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM
[    1.994974] pci 0000:00:1a.0: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001
[    3.595089] pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001
[    3.595298] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
```

You might be able to fix this by disabling legacy support for USB in your BIOS.

Your next challenge would be to fix the 4 seconds its taking to mount sda2

```
[    6.087480] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   10.736844] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

I'm not sure how you would go about doing this - maybe you could have a smaller root partition and somehow fsck a data partition while systemd is bringing other things up ?

Comment: i don't know how to disable legacy support for USB in my BIOS i use UEFI on my bios

Comment: here's fsck to sda2 `/dev/sda2  /  ext4 errors=remount-ro  0  1` should i set the last value to 0

Comment: No.  From the man page for fstab - "The  root filesystem  should be specified with a fs_passno of 1, and other filesystems should have a fs_passno of 2.  Filesystems within  a drive will be checked sequentially, but filesystems on different drives will be checked at the same time to  utilize  parallelism  available in the hardware.